Get row count with and without filters
Let's say I have the query below.
With one query execution, how can I return the total count as below and also the total count with just the t1.IsActive = 1 filter?
select 
    count(*)
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.empId = t2.empId
inner join Table3 t3 on t2.empId = t3.empId
inner join Table4 t4 on t3.empId = t4.empId
inner join Table5 t5 on t4.empId = t5.empId
inner join Table6 t6 on t5.empId = t6.empId
inner join Table7 t7 on t6.empId = t7.empId
where
    t1.IsActive = 1
    and t1.EmpId like '%Emp%'
    and t2.Company = 'A'
    and t3.St <> 'NY'


Conditional aggregation (putting a case expression inside an aggregate function) will do this.
select 
    count(*), 
    sum(case when t1.EmpId like '%Emp%' and t2.Company = 'A'and t3.St <> 'NY' then 1 end) 
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.empId = t2.empId
inner join Table3 t3 on t2.empId = t3.empId
inner join Table4 t4 on t3.empId = t4.empId
inner join Table5 t5 on t4.empId = t5.empId
inner join Table6 t6 on t5.empId = t6.empId
inner join Table7 t7 on t6.empId = t7.empId
where
    t1.IsActive = 1

